Derivatives of summation with respect to index
I'm attempting to work through the derivative of the NDCG loss function. This is not for class or any practical reason other than curiosity.
The function is below where the index, item pair $(x,i)$ represents the item relevance and item position, respectively.
$$ \frac{ 2^{x_i}  - 1} {log_2(i+1)} $$
I know that derivative of a sum is the sum of derivatives. However, I'm uncertain whether each item in the summation requires multi-variable differentiation. In practice, neither the relevance or position are fixed, both are hyper-parameters subject to optimization.
If I recall, in multi-variable differentiation, we consider the derivative of each variable with respect to itself while treating the others as constants and this vector of derivatives is the gradient.
Here is the work I've done so far.
Quotient rule $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{g^2(x)}$
Log base 2 $\frac{d}{dx} log_2(x) = \frac{1}{xln(2)}$
Derivatives

In the case of $\frac{d}{dx}$, the "g" term, $log_2(i+1)$ contains no reference to $x$, so it's treated like a constant and the final expression evaluates to $\frac{x_i 2^{x_i-1}}{log_2(i+1)}$

Tn the case of $\frac{d}{di}$, this one is a bit trickier because $x_i$ is indexed by $i$ but it's a distinct variable; thus, I would argue that we can treat it like a constant. If so, the derivative would evaluate to $\frac{ -2^{(x_i-1)} (i+1) ln(2)}{ (log_2(i+1) )^2 }$


However, I'd like confirmation that this is indeed accurate and why or why not if I've made a logical and/or execution error.


When $i$ is a discrete variable (such as an integer index), $\frac d{di}$ has no meaning. If one wants to optimize over $i$, one has to use some other method.
There's no variable $x$ in this expression, so it wouldn't be relevant to compute $\frac d{dx}$; since $x_i$ is a variable (for each fixed $i$), it does make sense to compute $\frac d{dx_i}$.
The derivative of the exponential function $2^{x_i}$ (with respect to $x_i$) is not $x_i2^{x_i-1}$, but rather $2^{x_i}\ln 2$.

